# How does increasing the pipe size affect water flow?

Tags: pressure, flow

I'm about to have a **1"** water meter installed. I'm wondering if a pipe diameter of **1 and 1/2"** pipe would increase the water flow, or will I be limited to the flow of the water through the water meter?

I hate the loss in water flow when 2 taps are on at once.

Comment: Pressure drop depends on flow rate, diameter and length of pipe. It is linear with length of pipe and goes as the inverse fourth power of diameter - going from 1" to 1/2" for a distance x is like increasing the length of 1" pipe to 16x. Whether that is significant in your situation depends on factors you didn't specify.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. So more detail. I believe the water pressure at the main line is 21 metres of head and the flow is 25 litres per minute. If i have an approx. 5 meters of 1" pipe (including the meter) followed by 30 meters of 1 and 1/2", will it be a significant increase over just 30 meters of 1" pipe?

Comment: There are many online calculators for this - try [this one](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/hazen-williams-water-d_797.html) for example. It looks like at 25 liter/min a 1" pipe will not give you a horrendous pressure drop.